# Can Gradle build Instrumentation tests without running them?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, gradlew

**TL:DR**
I am looking for a way to make sure our Instrumentation testing suite compiles, but without actually running it. Is it possible to achieve that using the Android plugin for `Gradle`?

I looked over [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests) and I don't see anything other than a Gradle command that compiles and then runs tests together.

The reason I am looking for this is we want to be able to run a build on every Pull Request but running the suite takes way too long. Yet we want to make sure the instrumentation suite at least compiles with all the code changes so it can run in its time.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the `Gradle` task to achieve this:

`$ ./gradlew compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac`

Above task will compile Instrumented tests without actually running them.

Answer (score 2):

Can be achieved, gradle is running everything as task, I hope you are executing:

```
./gradlew test
```

and you can see output as

```
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2501Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2501Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:incrementalDebugUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugUnitTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:app:assembleDebugUnitTest
:app:testDebugUnitTest
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:generateReleaseResValues
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:incrementalReleaseUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseUnitTestDependencies
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources
:app:assembleReleaseUnitTest
:app:testReleaseUnitTest
:app:test

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

which is tasks call hierarchy, means task "test" is dependent on all or one above task i.e. "app:testReleaseUnitTest". so you can call upto "assembleReleaseUnitTest"

```
./gradlew assembleReleaseUnitTest
```

Comment: Your answer might work for unit tests; however, for instrumentation tests task is different. Good call on looking up the list of Gradle tasks though!